# Devise Token Auth :authenticate_user! works wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If I add `before_action :authenticate_user!` to `ApplicationController`, I get an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: json.data @users, :name, :username
```

What comes from this file:

**show.jbuilder**

```
json.data @users, :name, :username
```

My controller:

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

If I remove `before_action :authenticate_user!` everything works just fine, I get JSON object with the list of users.

Why does it happen? Device usually returns `401`, but `devise_token_auth` is trying to trigger my `show` and fails because can't access database. How to fix this weird behaviour?

Comment: How does your implementation of `authenticate_user!` look like?

Comment: @jack what do you mean? :authenticate_user! is a Devise built-in helper method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is pretty idiosyncratic and your error is that you are sending a collection to a view that is built for a single resource.

In Rails the show action corresponds to viewing a single resource and usually relies on passing the ID via an `:id` parameter:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/:id
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

You don't need to explicitly call render either.

app/views/users/show.json.jbuilder:

```
json.(@user, :name, :username)
```

app/views/users/index.json.jbuilder:

```
json.comments @user do |json, user|
  json.(user, :name, :username)
end
```

Comment: IMHO `jbuilder` is a complete waste of time. ActiveModelSerializers is faster, easier to test and much dryer. The only reason jbuilder is included in Rails by default is that it is DHH's pet project.

Comment: This isn't my actual controller, it was written in one sec just for example of an error. The problem was in `jbuilder`, you're right. And thanks for ActiveModelSerializers suggetion. I will check that :)